# Using Django Templates with User Authentication

Tags: python, django, templates, django-allauth

I have a site which I am using user authentication to limit access to.
I am using `django-allauth` to handle social media authentication, but want to limit access to `staff` accounts only (set in the django admin panel).

I want to use a template as a header (bootstrap, nav bar etc.) with the main content loaded afterwards, or a message asking the user to login or request to be verified by admins.

My header template file: `inventory/header.html`

```
<body>
    {% load bootstrap3 %}

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% if user.is_staff%}
            {% block main %}{% endblock %}
            {% block scripts %}{% endblock %}
        {% else %}
            <h1>Please ask an administrator to activate your account</h1>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        <h1>Please login to see this page</h1>
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

And another template called by the view: `inventory/home.html`

```
{% include "inventory/header.html" %}
{% block main %}
    This is the home page.
{% endblock %}
```

The view:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request,'inventory/home.html')
```

Whenever I call the view, regardless of whether the user is logged in or a staff member, the `main` block is always displayed. The other error messages are displayed correctly.

I'm trying to avoid inserting `is_authenticated/is_staff` into all of my templates. I have also thought about using the `login_required` view decorator but that does not solve my `is_staff` issue.

Comment: You could try `if request.user.is_staff:  return render(request,'inventory/home.html') else: return render(request,'show_something_relevant.html')` in the home view.

Comment: I was thinking of that, but I was trying to avoid having this if condition in every view (I have around 15). I was hoping I could inherit the condition within the templates

Comment: does **user** is passed in the context of inventory/header.html.If not use `if request.user` instead `if user` in the template, like `if request.user.is_staff`.

Comment: Yes, user is passed. I even tried {% if False %}, and that included the block as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I should have used

```
{% extends "inventory/header.html" %}
```

instead of

```
{% include "inventory/header.html" %}
```

Doh!